# What does the "rep change" explanation in the reputation tab mean?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Recently, I was looking over my friend's reputation bar, and I saw a weird thing in it.
It said:

> +2 18:23       rep change       Rep Change

I found this kinda weird, since that could easily be put everywhere, as rep changes happen all the time, but they're specified.
Here's the image of the specified user's "rep change":

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Explained here https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231809/145673

Comment: Exactly what Martin said (moderators see a little more detail, I can confirm it was an automatic adjustment to keep the user from dropping below 1 point).

Comment: Explaining "rep change" with "Rep Change" is a brilliant solution.

Comment: SO is just as brilliant as some software documentation

Comment: @MartijnPieters does this open a loophole for abuse? It seems a user just over 100 rep could open a bounty, wait for the help it draws in, then delete the question. They'd have reaped the benefits of a bounty without actually paying anything for it.

Comment: @LordFarquaad: there are plenty of limitation in place on what you can delete. And all this does is get you back to 1, and you need a minimum rep amount to place a bounty. Exploiting this is going to be pretty hard, gives no real gain that I can see, and we can always deal with anyone trying this on manually.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Will the "rep change" be annulled when the post is subsequently undeleted?

Comment: @Bergi: yes, it will.

Comment: @LordFarquaad they can also accept no answers so they don't have to award the bounty. That's simpler and difficult to counter (like answers rarely being accepted whereas they're spot on with a comment from the OP sayng "perfect")

Comment: @honk [`commit -m 'Rep Change'`](https://xkcd.com/1296/)